# Getting english name of country instead of name in device language?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

How can I get english name of country instead of name in my choosen device language?

```
public static String getCountryName(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        Address result;

        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            return addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        //do something
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: have you tried changing `Locale.getDefault()` to `Locale.ENGLISH`?

Comment: No... I don't know how I couldn't see this... Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can mark @ChampS answer as the correct one. Since it's the same as my comment. So that the community would properly see it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using the default Locale? This should work:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
```